# How are Go-ethereum and Parity maintained and who maintains them?

Tags: go-ethereum, cli

**How are Go-ethereum and Parity maintained, who maintains them and where is the recommended point of access?**

I have had problems finding the latest versions of Geth and Parity:

First, the link behind "latest stable binary" (pointing to https://build.ethdev.com/builds/Windows%20Go%20master%20branch/) in page https://www.ethereum.org/cli#windows seems invalid. Browser responded with "The site can't be reached".

~~Then, I went to [Installation Instructions for Windows](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installation-instructions-for-Windows) in github. First line says "All versions of Geth are built and available for download at https://geth.ethereum.org/download/". But, oops https://geth.ethereum.org/download/ was 404.~~

eth has similar results too. http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/cpp-ethereum/installing-binaries/windows-installer.html is the link given at https://www.ethereum.org/cli but it returns 404 too.

Note: [Installation Instructions for Windows](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installation-instructions-for-Windows) was fixed to point to valid url.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Before Update 2: where do I download these tools?

Comment: After Update 2: Aren't these sites maintained?

Comment: Now I wonder, how did you managed to get all non existing links :D

Comment: @niksmac I didn't say "non-existing" (at least not in my original post; it's been "improved" since). I was saying "non-working". There is a difference between these two.

Answer (score 2):

For Geth, a good entry point is https://geth.ethereum.org/. You can find the binary downloads at https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads.

For Parity, the site is https://ethcore.io/parity.html. Downloads are found at the bottom of the page.

Both projects are managed as open-source efforts on github. They are both actively maintained, but sometimes links get broken. It's an open source, community-driven project, so if you have problems, you should file issues in the respective github repos:

- [Go-Ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum)
- [Parity](https://github.com/ethcore/parity)

You can see all recent commits and the developers who contributed them on the github pages. You'll notice that both projects have multiple commits by multiple developers in the last 24 hours.